How to convert a mapped object to JSON for uploading to Hashicorp Vault
I am trying to create SQL servers in Azure using Terraform, and create a JSON for uploading the login information to Hashicorp vault.  Here is my code:
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length      = 20
  upper       = true
  min_upper   = 1
  lower       = true
  min_lower   = 1
  number      = true
  min_numeric = 1
  special     = false
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "server" {
  for_each            = var.sql_servers
  name                = each.key
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
}

variable "sql_servers" {
  type = map(object({
    location            = string
    resource_group_name = string
  }))

variable "administrator_login" {
  type        = string
  description = "Admin login for the sql servers"
  default     = "admin_user"
}

locals {
  sql_server_login_info = [
    for key, server in var.sql_servers : {
      server_name             = key
      administrator_password  = random_string.password.result
      administrator_login     = var.administrator_login
    }
  ]
}

I want the output to look like this:
{
  server_name = server1
  admin_user = admin_user
  admin_password = password
}
{
  server_name = server2
  admin_user = admin_user
  admin_password = password
}
{
  server_name = server3
  admin_user = admin_user
  admin_password = password
}

I am attempting to upload this to Hashicorp vault with the following block:
resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "sql_vault" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_mssql_server.server]
  mount       = "dba-info"
  name       = "/some/path/in/hashicorp/vault"
  cas        = 1
  data_json  = jsonencode(local.sql_server_login_info)
}

However, I am getting the following error:
Error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}

I did some research and think I need to convert the local.sql_server_login_info into a different type before encoding it.  But I don't know if this is correct, and if so, I'm not sure how to do that.
Thanks.

The error you're getting looks to be due to the fact that jsonencode() expects a map, but you're passing in a list (local.sql_server_login_info), and Vault expects the data_json to be a key-value map.
You need to modify the structure of local.sql_server_login_info so that it is a map rather than a list, with the server names as keys. This will fix the issue.
You should create a map, not a list, so that each server's information’s key is its server name. Try using the following:
locals {
  sql_server_login_info = {
    for key, server in var.sql_servers : key => {
      administrator_password = random_string.password.result
      administrator_login    = var.administrator_login
    }
  }
}

And then pass the sql_server_login_info map directly into the data_json field, just like you already did:
resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "sql_vault" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_mssql_server.server]
  mount      = "dba-info"
  name       = "/some/path/in/hashicorp/vault"
  cas        = 1
  data_json  = jsonencode(local.sql_server_login_info)
}

This change will encode the data as a map with the server names as keys, which is what Vault expects. Note that with my suggestion, your output will look like this:
{
  "server1": {
    "admin_user": "admin_user",
    "admin_password": "password1"
  },
  "server2": {
    "admin_user": "admin_user",
    "admin_password": "password2"
  },
  "server3": {
    "admin_user": "admin_user",
    "admin_password": "password3"
  }
}

But this should resolve the issue with the jsonencode error and allow you to upload the login information to HashiCorp Vault successfully.
This is the approach I’ll take.

Note -
The exact output format you want is a bit tricky, as JSON does not support multiple independent objects without wrapping them in an array or another structure.
A workaround would be to use Terraform’s join() and string interpolation.
You can update the locals block to generate the desired output as a string:
locals {
  sql_server_login_info_string = join("\n", [
    for key, server in var.sql_servers : <<EOT
{
  server_name = ${key}
  admin_user = ${var.administrator_login}
  admin_password = ${random_string.password.result}
}
EOT
  ])
}

And then pass the formatted string to Vault (or output it).
If you want to store this in Vault, you can encode it as a string:
resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "sql_vault" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_mssql_server.server]
  mount      = "dba-info"
  name       = "/some/path/in/hashicorp/vault"
  cas        = 1
  data_json  = jsonencode({
    sql_info = local.sql_server_login_info_string
  })
}

The local.sql_server_login_info_string would look exactly as you want it, but as a single concatenated string.
{
  server_name = server1
  admin_user = admin_user
  admin_password = password1
}
{
  server_name = server2
  admin_user = admin_user
  admin_password = password2
}
{
  server_name = server3
  admin_user = admin_user
  admin_password = password3
}


This is working to put it in a JSON format, so vault will accept the upload.  However, it's coming out as one long string, and with a bunch of "/n", like: {
"sql_info": "{\n  server_name = servername\n  admin_user = admin_user\n  admin_password = 123456789\n}\n"
}
